# for loop is overwriting output

Tags: r, list, for-loop, substring

I have the following code but I am having trouble generating the output I want. The input is in a list that looks like this:

```
>spl
$A
V1                                          V2
1  A   LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
2  A   DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
3  A   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

$B
 V1                                        V2
4  B     ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
5  B     MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
6  B     HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk




s1 <- read.table('~/Downloads/tst.txt', header=F)
spl <- split(s1, f=s1$V1)

 for (i in length(spl)){
  seqs <- spl[[i]]$V2
  for (last in seq(length(spl[[i]]$V2), to=2)){
    frontseq <- substring(seqs[last],  max(nchar(as.character(seqs[last]))-16),max(nchar(as.character(seqs[last]))))
    }
  for (first in seq(length(spl[[i]]$V2), to=2)){
    endseq <- substring(seqs[first], 1, 16)
   }
  join.out <- rbind(join.out, paste(frontseq, endseq, sep=''))
 }
```

the output I want joins the ends of one line with the beginning of another:

Basically, the last substring (of length 16) of the last line in for spl[1] should join be joined with the first substring of the sam length of that same line **and** with the first substring of the second line in spl[1]. Then, the last substring of the second line in spl[1] should be joined with the beginning substring of that same line. The same thing should then happen for spl[2]. Line #1 should just be ignored always.

So the output **should** look like this:

```
A  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
A  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
A  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
B  kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
B  kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
B  zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
```

Instead it seems like I am overwriting the output and I'm generating something that looks like this.

```
     [,1]                               
[1,] "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM""
```

How can I prevent the for loop from overwriting the output?

Comment: drop the `max` since nchar is just a single number so you want `nchar(string)-16` and then `nchar`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. The output is still getting overwritten though

Comment: if spl is a list, you can't do something like `spl[[i]]$V2`

Comment: I am splitting a table using the `split` function to generate spl. And I am then selecting column 2 of that item in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for (i in length(spl))` is the same as `for (i in 2)` so your outer loop only executes once.

Your inner loops execute twice each (`3:2`), but overwrite `endseq` and `frontseq` each time, so you only get one element on `join.out`.

---

Update: Here's an `lapply` solution that I recombine with `do.call` and `rbind`. I think this meets your logic.

```
s1 <- read.table(textConnection("A   LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
A   DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
A   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
B     ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
B     MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
B     HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
spl <- split(s1, f=s1$V1)
myFun <- function(x) {
    x <- x[nrow(x):2, ]
    front <- substring(x$V2, nchar(x$V2) - 16, nchar(x$V2))
    front <- c(front[1], front)
    back <- substring(x$V2, 1, 16)
    back <- c(back, back[length(back)])
    data.frame(paste0(front, back))
}
do.call(rbind, lapply(spl, myFun))
```

Comment: I fixed the first loop `for (i in 1:length(spl))` but the two inner loops I'm not sure how to fix. When I try this for example, it still overwrites the output `frontseq[last] <- `

Comment: I'll post an `lapply` solution. Here your operations (as far as I can tell) are independent between list elements, so an `lapply` solution is a little easier for me to understand.